# Mediawiki css/html infobox creating blank rows

Tags: html, css, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I'm very new to MediaWiki, HTML, CSS, and programming in general. I'm using the ParserFunctions extension for the if statement to delete the rows when its empty. When I use the template, for every two rows that are deleted, it creates 1 blank row on top. Also the issue with 'Spouse(s)' being indented annoys me, is there a way to change that?

[All rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rbkp4.png)
[Two rows removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwSes.png)
css:

```
{{#css:
  .infobox {
    width: 270px;
    color: #000000;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }
  .infobox td:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: left;
    
  }
  .infobox td:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 100px;
  .infobox tr:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}}
```

html:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #aaa; background-color: #F8F9FA; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: 90%; float: right; margin: 0 0 10px 10px;">
{| class="infobox"
| <tr><th style="background-color: #99BADD; font-size: 120%; width: 30%; vertical-align: top;" colspan="2">{{{name}}}</th></tr>
| <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><img src="{{{image}}}" alt="{{{alt}}}" /></td></tr>
| <tr><th colspan="2" style="background-color: #CCBBEE;">{{{title}}}</th></tr>
{{#if: {{{birth|}}}
  | <tr><td>Born</td><td>{{{birth}}}<br>{{{birth-place}}}</td></tr>
}}
{{#if: {{{death|}}}
  | <tr><td>Died</td><td>{{{death}}}<br>{{{death-place}}}</td></tr>
}}
{{#if: {{{house|}}}
  | <tr><td>House</td><td>{{{house}}}</td></tr>
}}
{{#if: {{{spouse|}}}
  | <tr><td>Spouse(s)</td><td>{{{spouse}}}</td></tr>
}}
{{#if: {{{issue|}}}
  | <tr><td>Issue</td><td>{{{issue}}}</td></tr>
}}
{{#if: {{{father|}}}
  | <tr><td>Father</td><td>{{{father}}}</td></tr>
}}
{{#if: {{{mother|}}}
  | <tr><td>Mother</td><td>{{{mother}}}</td></tr>
}}
</div>
```

I tried some css properties but none seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you put enters between the `{{#if` statements. A double enter is interpreted by mediawiki as an empty paragraph, resulting in some empty space in your table.

You can resolve as follows:

1. Escape your enters:

```html
{{#if: FOO|
Bar
}}<!--
-->{{#if: Baz|
Qux
}}<!--
etc -->
```

2. Do not write enters:

```html
{{#if: FOO|
Bar
}}<!-- no enter here! -->{{#if: Baz|
Qux
}}<!-- etc -->
```

Besides this, you are using a weird mix of Mediawiki table-syntax and html table-syntax. I suggest you write everything as either one. In my experience, html table-syntax is more robust.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #aaa; background-color: #F8F9FA; padding: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: 90%; float: right; margin: 0 0 10px 10px;">
<table class="infobox">
<tr><th style="background-color: #99BADD; font-size: 120%; width: 30%; vertical-align: top;" colspan="2">{{{name}}}</th></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><img src="{{{image}}}" alt="{{{alt}}}" /></td></tr>
<tr><th colspan="2" style="background-color: #CCBBEE;">{{{title}}}</th></tr><!--
-->{{#if: {{{birth|}}}
|<tr><td>Born</td><td>{{{birth}}}<br>{{{birth-place}}}</td></tr>
}}{{#if: {{{death|}}}
|<tr><td>Died</td><td>{{{death}}}<br>{{{death-place}}}</td></tr>
}}{{#if: {{{house|}}}
  | <tr><td>House</td><td>{{{house}}}</td></tr>
}}{{#if: {{{spouse|}}}
| <tr><td>Spouse(s)</td><td>{{{spouse}}}</td></tr>
}}{{#if: {{{issue|}}}
| <tr><td>Issue</td><td>{{{issue}}}</td></tr>
}}{{#if: {{{father|}}}
| <tr><td>Father</td><td>{{{father}}}</td></tr>
}}{{#if: {{{mother|}}}
| <tr><td>Mother</td><td>{{{mother}}}</td></tr>
}}</table>
</div>
```